# How to get entire string at line of caret position into RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and seems that there is not CaretPosition function into richtextbox propreties.
How can i get the entire rows at caret position?
For example I've written this:

```
              show databases;
              show tables;/* (the caret (|) is flashing just here so after pressing a button i want to display "show tables"*/
              show functions;
```

How can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you could show your code, we might be able to be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **WPF**:

```
        TextPointer caretPos = rtb.CaretPosition;
        TextPointer start=caretPos.GetLineStartPosition(0);
        TextPointer end = (caretPos.GetLineStartPosition(1) != null ? caretPos.GetLineStartPosition(1) : caretPos.DocumentEnd);

        TextRange tr = new TextRange(start, end);
        MessageBox.Show(tr.Text);
```

`GetLineStartPosition(0)` returns a `TextPointer` object with position the start of the current line.
`GetLineStartPosition(1)` returns a `TextPointer` object with position the start of the next line.

If the caret is placed in the last line, the `caretPos.GetLineStartPosition(1)` will return null. You can fix this by using the `caretPos.DocumentEnd`.

If you are using **WinForms**:

```
        string[] lines = rtb.Lines;
        MessageBox.Show(lines[rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(rtb.SelectionStart)]);
```

`rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(rtb.SelectionStart)` method returns the number of the line where the caret is placed.

Answer (score 0):

There most certainly **is** a [RichTextBox.CaretPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property available as of .NET Framework version 3.0.

Comment: No, in my class I haven't GetCarPosition, in the intellisense it doesn't appear.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 with 3.5 Net Framework, I know is strange, but GetCarPosition doesn't exist.

Comment: I agree that `GetCarPosition` does not exist in the 3.5 framework, but `CaretPosition` certainly does, [as seen in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: He is using WinForms.